# How many peers it MultiBit connected to? Can not send bitcoins

Tags: multibit, peers

I have received bitcoins from an online wallet and I am now trying to send 0.05 BTC to another address. I have by now figured out that I need to set at least 0.0001 BTC as a sender fee (that error message was confusing, because it appears *before* has the opportunity to set that fee!).

I am now getting the error message “MultiBit must be online and connected to more than one peer to send bitcoin”. I can see from the status in the lower left corner that MultiBit is online, but I can not see the number of peers.

[image: screenshot of MultiBit 0.5.14 showing error message]

- How can I check the number of peers?
- Why is MultiBit not connected to more than one peer (if any)?
- How long can it take to connect to more than one peer?

I am using MultiBit 0.5.14 with Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hover over the "Online" indicator to see the number of peers.

It should only take a few seconds to find more peers. This is dependent on the Bitcoin network though. You can force MultiBit to attempt to connect to a whole new set of peers by restarting it.